# Graphic in line with listing code name

Tags: templates, code

This snippet of code is derived from [Harvey Sheppard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/279318#279318).

I was attempting to get his `lstlisting` environment to work and appear like this:

[image]

I am not getting the `\codeimg` to show up (the graphic before the code title). Can you tell me what has to be done so that the graphic will show up before the code title like the image above?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{report}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\newcommand{\codeimg}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}}

\usepackage{metalogo} % typeset xelatex!
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
% \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}

% infoBulle skeleton
%\newenvironment{@infoBulleSkeletonEnv}[3]{
%   \begin{infoBulle}[style=#1, frametitle=\@titleContent{#2}{#3}]
%       \vspace*{-1mm}
%   }{
%\end{infoBulle}
%}
%\newcommand{\@infoBulleSkeleton}[4]{
%   \begin{@infoBulleSkeletonEnv}{#1}{#2}{#3}
%       #4
%   \end{@infoBulleSkeletonEnv}
%}
%\newcommand{\@codeTitle}{Title unchanged}
\newcommand{\codeTitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\@codeTitle}{#1}}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{yCode}{
    \begin{@infoBulleSkeletonEnv}{code}{\codeimg}{\@codeTitle}
}

\AfterEndEnvironment{yCode}{
    \end{@infoBulleSkeletonEnv}
}

\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47} % some dark red
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Coding environment (redefining lstlisting)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\codeTitle}[2]{Code}
\renewcommand{\codeTitle}{\hspace*{3mm}\begin{minipage}{.75cm}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\pathToInfoBulleImages code2.png}
    \end{minipage}\hspace*{1mm}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-1.05cm}
    {\sffamily\Large \codeTitle}
\end{minipage}}

\renewcommand*{\lstlistlistingname}{Liste des codes}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{ %ce code met tous les lstlistings dans un mdframed
    \begin{mdframed}[
        linecolor=Gray,
        backgroundcolor=light-gray,
        skipabove=4mm,
        skipbelow=0mm,
        innertopmargin=2mm,
        innerbottommargin=0mm,
        innerleftmargin=0mm,
        innerrightmargin=10pt,
        leftmargin=0mm,
        rightline=false,
        topline=false,
        bottomline=false,
        linewidth=1mm
        ]
        \codeTitle
        \vspace*{-2mm}
    }
    \AfterEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{
    \end{mdframed}
}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\lstset{
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    keywords={var, func, extends},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,% marge ajouté à gauche du tableau (à configurer en dernier pour l'alignement global du tableau)
    framesep=2mm, %distance texte bord du cadre (limite de la background color)
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip
}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\codeTitle}{Les bases de GDScript}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=basics.gd]
var nombreDeGardes = 4 #déclaration d'une variable
nombreDeGardes = plusDeux(nombreDeGardes) #appel d'une fonction avec la variable nombreDeGardes passée en paramètre

func maFonction(): #cette ligne déclare une nouvelle fonction nommée maFonction
    var variable1 = 7 #nouvelle variable dont la valeur est 7
    variable2 = ['un', 'deux', 'trois'] #variable assignée à un tableau contenant trois chaines de caractères

func plusDeux(argument1):
    return argument1 + 2
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a `tcolorbox`-based listing (module `listings`)?

Comment: @TeXnician...thanks, can you offer some more guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution with `tcolorbox`. You can format the title freely (`title` attribute of new environment). It works with all engines.

The only advantages over Ignazi's version:

- uses listingname from package
- is breakable (over pages)

[image: tcolorbox]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{report}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\newcommand{\codeimg}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}

\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47} % some dark red

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\lstset{
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    keywords={var, func, extends},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,% marge ajouté à gauche du tableau (à configurer en dernier pour l'alignement global du tableau)
    framesep=2mm, %distance texte bord du cadre (limite de la background color)
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip
}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings}
\newtcblisting[use counter=lstlisting]{codeblock}[2][]{%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}~#2},%
        title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting~--~continued},%
        listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm},after upper={\centering\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting:~#2},
        frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,frame code={\draw[gray,line width=2mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{codeblock}{Les bases de GDScript}
var nombreDeGardes = 4 #déclaration d'une variable
nombreDeGardes = plusDeux(nombreDeGardes) #appel d'une fonction avec la variable nombreDeGardes passée en paramètre

func maFonction(): #cette ligne déclare une nouvelle fonction nommée maFonction
    var variable1 = 7 #nouvelle variable dont la valeur est 7
    variable2 = ['un', 'deux', 'trois'] #variable assignée à un tableau contenant trois chaines de caractères

func plusDeux(argument1):
    return argument1 + 2
\end{codeblock}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I don't use `lualatex` or `xelatex` I don't know why following code doesn't work with them, but with `pdflatex` it shows how to define similar listing boxes with `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{report}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}

\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47} % some dark red

\lstset{
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 5mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    keywords={var, func, extends},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,% marge ajouté à gauche du tableau (à configurer en dernier pour l'alignement global du tableau)
    framesep=2mm, %distance texte bord du cadre (limite de la background color)
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip
}

\newtcblisting[auto counter, number within=chapter]{mylisting}[3][]{%
    listing only, 
    enhanced, 
    sharp corners, 
    colframe=light-gray,
    colback=light-gray,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\sffamily\Large,
    overlay={%
            \fill[white] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);
            \draw[line width=1mm,Gray] ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=5mm]frame.south west);
    },
    title={\ \includegraphics[width=5mm]{example-image-a}\ #2},
    after upper={\par\centering \textsf{Code~\thetcbcounter:~#3}},
    #1
    }

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}

\section{Section title}

\begin{mylisting}{Les bases de GDScript}{basics.gd}
var nombreDeGardes = 4 #déclaration d'une variable
nombreDeGardes = plusDeux(nombreDeGardes) #appel d'une fonction avec la variable nombreDeGardes passée en paramètre

func maFonction(): #cette ligne déclare une nouvelle fonction nommée maFonction
    var variable1 = 7 #nouvelle variable dont la valeur est 7
    variable2 = ['un', 'deux', 'trois'] #variable assignée à un tableau contenant trois chaines de caractères

func plusDeux(argument1):
    return argument1 + 2
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your input, but how come there is no color?  The `xcolor` option is activated?  How can you get the code to show up in color?  Thanks.