# Graphic in line with listing code name part 3

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

This code is building from the [solution posted here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353248/graphic-in-line-with-listing-code-name-part-2).

If this `tcolorbox` environment is used within a paragraph, the left gray line disappears...

[image]

How do you retain the look of the `listing` with the gray line to the left?  Thanks.

Here is the code...

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{report}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\newcommand{\codeimg}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}

\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47} % some dark red

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\lstset{
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    keywords={var, func, extends},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,% marge ajouté à gauche du tableau (à configurer en dernier pour l'alignement global du tableau)
    framesep=2mm, %distance texte bord du cadre (limite de la background color)
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip
}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings}
\newtcblisting[use counter=lstlisting]{codeblock}[2][]%
  {enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,
   colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,fonttitle=\bfseries,
   before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\raisebox{-3pt}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}~#2},
   title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting~--~continued},
   listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm},
   after upper={\centering\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting:~#2},
   frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,
   frame code={\draw[gray,line width=2mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},
   #1
  }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\par

\begin{codeblock}{Les bases de GDScript}
var nombreDeGardes = 4 #déclaration d'une variable
nombreDeGardes = plusDeux(nombreDeGardes) #appel d'une fonction avec la variable nombreDeGardes passée en paramètre

func maFonction(): #cette ligne déclare une nouvelle fonction nommée maFonction
    var variable1 = 7 #nouvelle variable dont la valeur est 7
    variable2 = ['un', 'deux', 'trois'] #variable assignée à un tableau contenant trois chaines de caractères

func plusDeux(argument1):
    return argument1 + 2
\end{codeblock}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Rather then `frame code` try with `overlay`

Comment: Your problem is not the paragraph, but the page break. If it doesn't break the page the code is fine, but with page break `tikz` can't calculate the path.

Comment: @SalimBou Your version works fine. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: @SalimBou, can you please provide me with some more guidance as to how to implement your solution?  Thanks!

Comment: Just replace `frame code` with `overlay` and the line appears again. On the second fragment the line also covers part of the continuation title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for protocol the answer from the comments. Your problem is not the paragraph, but the page break. This causes the TikZ code in `frame code` to mess up. Your problem can be solved using `overlay` instead.

```
\newtcblisting[use counter=lstlisting]{codeblock}[2][]%
  {enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,
   colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,fonttitle=\bfseries,
   before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\raisebox{-3pt}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}~#2},
   title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting~--~continued},
   listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm},
   after upper={\centering\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting:~#2},
   frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,
   overlay={\draw[gray,line width=2mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},
   #1
  }
```